# MongoDB aggregation - show values from different arrays in one array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this type of data

```
{ 
"_id" : 6444, 
"name" : [
    {
        "name" : "John", 
        "sourcesID" : [
            1, 
            2
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Jack", 
        "sourcesID" : [
            3, 
            4 
        ]
    }       
    ],
"address" : [
    {
        "city" : "Chicago", 
        "sourcesID" : [
            3, 
            4 
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "city" : "Boston", 
        "sourcesID" : [
            5, 
            6
        ]
    }       
]
```

}

I want to aggregate the data so that I will be able to match a certain sourcesID and find all the information types that came from this source.

This is what I am looking to achieve

```
{"type" : "name", "sourceID" : 1}
{"type" : "name", "sourceID" : 2}
{"type" : "name", "sourceID" : 3}
{"type" : "name", "sourceID" : 4}
{"type" : "address", "sourceID" : 3}
{"type" : "address", "sourceID" : 4}
{"type" : "address", "sourceID" : 5}
{"type" : "address", "sourceID" : 6}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it always `sourcesID` or sometimes `sources` and sometimes `sourcesID` or it's totally unpredictable ?

Comment: Good catch! It's a mistake in my example. All should be sourcesID. Will fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there's always `sourceID` field you can run [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to transform be able to read object keys dynamically and then run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) three times to get single document per `sourceID`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            data: {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                    cond: {
                        $ne: [ "$$this.k", "_id" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    { $unwind: "$data.v" },
    { $unwind: "$data.v.sourcesID" },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            type: "$data.k",
            sourceID: "$data.v.sourcesID"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PmG74DqZ77S)